# How does one alias JSON in a Julia struct like in Go?

Tags: json, serialization, struct, julia

In GoLang, one can alias JSON for serializing and serializing/de-serializing:

```
 type Response struct {
      TaskID     string     `json:"task_id"`
 ...
 }
 ...
 func Run(task structs.Task) {
      msg := structs.Response{}
      msg.TaskID = task.TaskID
      resp, _ := json.Marshal(msg)
 ...
 }
```

`json:"task_id"` is the alias for the struct field `TaskID` with the `string` type in the `Response` struct of the GoLang example above.  This alias can be used to serialize the struct data into JSON as exemplified in `json.Marshal(msg)`

How can one accomplish this in Julia?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what you mean by "alias"?

Comment: I edited the question to further explain json aliasing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [StructTypes.names](https://juliadata.github.io/StructTypes.jl/stable/#StructTypes.names) function:

```
using JSON3
using StructTypes

Base.@kwdef mutable struct Foo
    task_id::Int = 0
    bar::String  = ""
end
StructTypes.StructType(::Type{Foo}) = StructTypes.Mutable()
StructTypes.names(::Type{Foo}) = ((:task_id, :TASKID), )
```

With these definitions serialization and deserialization looks like this

```
julia> f1 = JSON3.read("{\"TASKID\": 1, \"bar\": \"hello\"}", Foo)
Foo(1, "hello")

julia> JSON3.write(f1)
"{\"TASKID\":1,\"bar\":\"hello\"}"
```